# Hardware-specific questions

Tags: hardware

I'm good at programming yet I feel like I don't know enough about the architecture of the hardware I'm working on.

- What does the Northbridge on the mainboard do?
- What does the L2 cache of my processor do?
- Can Windows XP use multiple processors? Not in terms of concrete multitasking in all programs but using the capacity of all cores if needed instead of always only one core.
- How can my processor/mainboard interact with multiple kinds of graphics/sound cards?

Comment: I would post separate questions on superuser rather than posting several vague questions here. You'll get better responses that way.

Answer (score -1):

North bridge control Memory usually, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing)
L2 cache info http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/cache-size-matter,1709.html

etc etc

These answers can be resolved/answered via google and 15min  :)